# Backreferences in jq like sed or vi?

Tags: jq, backreference

I have the following string in my input to `jq`:

`"\n*blah\n**tim\nbob was here\n*item1\n**item2\n"`

And I'm able to match the first `\n*` with the following:

`[match("(\n\\*[A-Za-z0-9]*\n)";"g")]`

Which gives me the following matches:

```
[
  {
    "offset": 0,
    "length": 7,
    "string": "\n*blah\n",
    "captures": [
      {
        "offset": 0,
        "length": 7,
        "string": "\n*blah\n",
        "name": null
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "offset": 25,
    "length": 8,
    "string": "\n*item1\n",
    "captures": [
      {
        "offset": 25,
        "length": 8,
        "string": "\n*item1\n",
        "name": null
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

My goal however, is to search for these and add an extra `\n` to the start of the matched `\n*` lines.

I don't appear to be able to do backreferences using gsub, so is there a similar functionality to what can be done in `sed` and `vi` using backreference matches in `jq`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a demonstration using a named capture `?<a>` with [sub](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#RegularexpressionsPCRE) and [gsub](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#RegularexpressionsPCRE):

```
$ jq -Mn '
  "\n*blah\n**tim\nbob was here\n*item1\n**item2\n"
|    sub("(?<a>\n\\*[A-Za-z0-9]*\n)";"\n\(.a)";"g")
  , gsub("(?<a>\n\\*[A-Za-z0-9]*\n)";"\n\(.a)")
'
```

output

```
"\n\n*blah\n**tim\nbob was here\n\n*item1\n**item2\n"
"\n\n*blah\n**tim\nbob was here\n\n*item1\n**item2\n"
```

Comment: So what is the official syntax on this?  Do you need the `?<a>` there and it has to be between the parenthesis just like the expression it matches?

Comment: The [manual](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#RegularexpressionsPCRE) is a bit terse on this and it helps to read the entire section.  The [implementation](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/blob/master/src/builtin.jq#L115-L153) appears to depend on what [match](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/blob/master/src/builtin.c#L753) stores into `.captures` so I don't think backreferences are supported which is curious because jq uses [oniguruma](https://github.com/kkos/oniguruma/blob/master/doc/RE) to do the regex work and it seems to support them.  Perhaps they are only allowed in the search pattern.